# Crear API rest con parámetros json

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

estuve consultando, y no sé si será porque no sé manejarlo o que, pero necesito crear una API en C# a la que le pueda pasar parámetros por JSON, no por URL, como estoy manejando actualmente.
Estoy manejando asp.net con la versión del framework 4.6.1

Comment: cuando dices asp.net te refieres a asp.net mvc ? porque con esta puedes crear una web api

Comment: Pido disculpas, si, es aspectos.net mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias crear una `web api` con `asp-net mvc` y exponer la funcionalidad mediente el verbo http `post`

[Get Started with ASP.NET Web API 2 (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

[Implementando Web API en ASP.NET MVC](https://msmdotnet.wordpress.com/2015/12/01/implementando-web-api-en-asp-net-mvc/)

Entonces basicamente puedes crear una entidad que mapee con tu json, para eso ayudate de

http://json2csharp.com/

podria ser digamos una entidad producto

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

la cual puedes usar en el controller

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{

    [Httppost]
    public void Post(Product product)
    {
        //aqui persistes
    }
}
```

como veras el action del controller esta decorado con [HttpPost] si envias el json que mapea con la estructura de la clase `model binding` de asp.net mvc lo convierte a objeto, despues solo queda que lo valides y lo persistas usando entity framework

Comment: era mas sencillo de lo que pensaba, gracias!